# Unable to reach the router's configuration page

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have a [TP-Link WR702N nano router](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/TL-WR702N.html). After many unsuccessful attempts to change the router configuration, I  reset the router, after which the SSID was reset to a TP-Link default and it's an open network now.

The issue is: I tried pinging the router's config IP: 192.168.1.253 (from the router's manual) and got the following message:

> Destination host unreachable.

But, I'm able to connect to the internet after logging in through my network's captive login portal.

Running the windows troubleshooter gives me the following message:

> Your computer appears to be correctly configured but the device or resource (192.168.1.253) is not responding.

Any suggestions on what I should do? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: IP address is set to be obtained automatically. The same applies to DNS.

Comment: Open a command prompt and run `ipconfig /all`. Look for the standard gateway address. Plug that into your browser instead of 192.168.1.253 and see if it works any better.

Comment: The gateway address takes me to the switch's login portal and not my router's.

Answer (score 1):

Reset the router, use ethernet to configure it at the stated default address.
TP-Link can be unreliable. If you DO hard-reset it, make sure you follow the instructions 100% accurately. Especially *how long to hold down the button(s)* to make it reset. 
The rest of the answer requires more knowledge of what you're trying to do with the network, the topology of it and whatever "network's captive login portal" means. If it's your network, why the captive login portal? Is this over WiFi or ethernet? What mode is the TP-Link router in?